# Using Wildcards with Content Assist in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I would like to know if there is any way to use wildcards when using content assist in Ecilpse.  For example, today I wanted to find the various classes on the classpath that ended in 'Exception'.  I tried the following combinations, but in each instance content assist only brought up classes or interfaces that started with 'Exception'

```
.Exception [cntl]+[space bar]
?Exception [cntl]+[space bar]
#Exception [cntl]+[space bar]
*Exception [cntl]+[space bar]
```

Please note I did try googling this, but didn't find any answers based upon the following search criteria 'eclipse wildcard content assist'.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can.

It's not exactly what you're after, but you can open the "Open Type" dialog and use wildcards there. Ctrl+Shift+T will open the dialog.

You can also use just the capitals from the type name in the "Open Type" dialog. For example typing NPEx will bring up NoPermissionException and NullPointerException.