# Eclipse auto completion: How to show only those methods with a specific pattern/wildcard?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, wildcard

I often know only parts of a method, I would like to call, but not the whole name (especially not the beginning). 
So I'd like to know, if there is a possibility to type in a pattern/wildcard while auto completion is active.
Thanks in advance!

```
// I'd like to call str.toUpperCase() but imagine I don't know that it starts with to
String str = "some string";
str.*upper // sth like that while auto completion is active
```

#### See also

> [Using Wildcards with Content Assist in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200659/using-wildcards-with-content-assist-in-eclipse)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Wildcards with Content Assist in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200659/using-wildcards-with-content-assist-in-eclipse)